# How to make border on FloatingActionButton?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

my problem is i want to do border around my floatingactionbutton. I tried to put it into container and do like this, but it's not what i want.

```
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.brown, width: 5, style: BorderStyle.solid)),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 55),
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          focusColor: Colors.white54,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 50,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

**I have this:**

[image]

**I want this:**

[image]

Comment: what you actually want can you share any images

Comment: I want this square to by rounded like button

Comment: You can achieve the same without wrapping it to Container, check answer.

Comment: Yup i know it, thx, but i actually need it to resize button

Comment: resize + Icon size or whole button?

Comment: to resize whole button

Comment: Okay for that I will prefer to use SizedBox rather than Container and rest is as per your suitability .

Comment: okey thx ur right

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In **FloatingActionButton** widget you have `property` named `shape` using that you can achieve your desired result.

```
   FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: (){},
          child: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.black,size: 30,),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide(width: 3,color: Colors.brown),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

just use `shape: BoxShape.circle,`

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.brown, width: 5, style: BorderStyle.solid)),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 55),
      width: 80,
      height: 80,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        focusColor: Colors.white54,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.black,
          size: 50,
        ),
      ),

    )
```

output:

[image]

Comment: we gucci thx mate

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
   Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    80,
                  ),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    width: 5,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                  ),
                ),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 55),
                width: 80,
                height: 80,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  focusColor: Colors.white54,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 50,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]